# Множественное воспроизведение звука

Tags: mediaplayer, android, аудио

Надеюсь, это мой последний вопрос по теме звука. Возникла финальная проблема, как реализовать возможность нескольких воспроизведений .wav файлов. Т.е я сделал воспроизведение при нажатии, когда я нажал 10 раз подряд (да хоть cто) он проигрывает один раз и ждет пока закончит, я жду пока он проигрывает, потом нажимаю и он проигрывает снова, а мне нужно, что бы он начинал воспроизводить этот же клип, не дожидаясь, как доиграет первый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);

int first  = sp.load(this, R.raw.first, 1);
int second = sp.load(this, R.raw.second, 1);

sp.play(first, LEFT, RIGHT, 1, 0, 1);
sp.play(second, LEFT, RIGHT, 1, 0, 2);
```

Неплохой пример есть здесь (Creating Sound Effects in Android): [Part 1](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html), [Part 2](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Оба способа работают.